# Unable to define stages for the projection.matrix function from the popbio package in R

Tags: r, matrix, popbio

I am trying to create a projection matrix and calculate bootstrap transitions following the example given in "Stubben & Milligan, 2007. Estimating and analyzing demographic models using the popbio package in R. Journal of Statistical Software, 22(1), 1-23" but am having trouble with the projection.matrix function from popbio, which seems to be considering the "dead" state as a stage.

Here is a portion of my data:

```
fateAK=data.frame(list(ID=c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,8,8,8,9,9,9,9,9,9,10,10,10,10,10,10,10), year=c(1983,1984,1983,1984,1983,1984,1983,1984,1985,1986,1987,1988,1989,1990,1983,1984,1985,1986,1987,1988,1989,1990,1983,1984,1985,1986,1987,1983,1984,1985,1986,1987,1988,1989,1990,1983,1984,1985,1986,1987,1988,1983,1984,1985,1986,1987,1988,1983,1984,1985,1986,1987,1988,1989),stage=c("Infant", "dead","Infant", "dead","Infant", "dead","Juvenile", "Juvenile","Juvenile", "Adult","Adult","Adult","Adult","Adult","Juvenile", "Juvenile","Juvenile", "Adult","Adult","Adult","Adult","Adult","Juvenile", "Juvenile","Adult","Adult","dead","Juvenile", "Adult","Adult","Adult","Adult","Adult", "Adult","Adult","Adult","Adult", "Adult","Adult","Senescent","dead","Adult","Adult", "Adult","Adult","Senescent","dead","Adult","Adult", "Adult","Adult","Senescent","Senescent", "dead"),fertility=c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0)))
```

And my code:

```
# build stage-fate dataframe
trans = subset(merge(fateAK, fateAK, by="ID", sort=FALSE), year.x==year.y-1)

#rename columns
colnames(trans)=c("ID", "year", "stage", "fertility",  "year2", "fate", "fertility2")    

#order stages
stages <- c("Infant", "Juvenile", "Adult", "Senescent")
trans$stage<-ordered(trans$stage, levels=stages)

#projection matrix - does not work
projection.matrix(trans, sort = stages, fertility=fertility)
```

Which gives a matrix with "dead" as a stage:

```
                Infant   Juvenile      Adult  Senescent
Adult     0.00000000 0.44444444 1.64285714 0.75000000
dead      1.00000000 0.00000000 0.03571429 0.75000000
Juvenile  0.00000000 0.55555556 0.00000000 0.00000000
Senescent 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.10714286 0.25000000
```

and the following warning message:

> Warning message:
> Error sorting matrix.
> Make sure that levels in stage and fate columns
> match stages listed in sort option above.
> Printing unsorted matrix instead!

I can't seem to figure out why "dead" would be considered a stage here, but wasn't in the example that I followed.

Any suggestion would be great! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

The "Infant" class is missing from fate, so you need to order the fate column too.

```
trans$fate <- ordered(trans$fate, levels=c(stages, "dead"))
```

The transition frequency table is created by running `prop.table(table())` and you need the factor levels in fate to get the first row with the missing Infant class below (and then `projection.matrix` will sort by stage to remove the "dead" row).

```
prop.table(table(trans$fate, trans$stage), 2)        
                Infant   Juvenile      Adult  Senescent
  Infant    0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000
  Juvenile  0.00000000 0.55555556 0.00000000 0.00000000
  Adult     0.00000000 0.44444444 0.85714286 0.00000000
  Senescent 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.10714286 0.25000000
  dead      1.00000000 0.00000000 0.03571429 0.75000000
```

Finally, the `projection.matrix` function is not the best and only works in a few cases like plants with a pre-breeding census (so newborn survival is included in the fertility estimate).  I would also try to define your matrix in terms of vital rates and see if that makes sense, check the popbio [wiki](https://github.com/cstubben/popbio/wiki/Creating-projection-matrices) for more details